# No s2s connection found in ejabberd android for usersearchManager return 503 in android App

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm new to ejabberd android. I can send and receive the messages successfully but I m not able to search user details using UserSearchManager in android it returns 503 error always.my code is below:

Code:

```
//mConnection in XMPP Connection  Object
UserSearchManager usm = new UserSearchManager(mConnection);
List<String> services = usm.getSearchServices();
//usm.gersearchservice() size always 0
//if (services == null || services.size() < 1)
for (String service: services) {
    Log.e("SERVICE", service);
}
Form searchForm = usm.getSearchForm("service."+mConnection.getServiceName());
Form answerForm = searchForm.createAnswerForm();
answerForm.setAnswer("Username", true);
answerForm.setAnswer("search", "ashok25");
ReportedData data = null;
data = usm.getSearchResults(answerForm, mConnection.getServiceName());
Iterator<ReportedData.Row> it = (Iterator<ReportedData.Row>) data.getRows();
```

Result:

```
D/SMACK: SENT (0): <iq to='search.xxx.yyy.zzz' id='59h51-23' type='get'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:search'/></iq>
D/SMACK: RECV (0): <iq from='search.xxx.yyy.zzz' to='ashok@search.xxx.yyy.zzz/Smack' type='error' xml:lang='en' id='59h51-23'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:search'/><error code='503' type='cancel'><service-unavailable xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/><text xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'>No s2s connection found</text></error></iq><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? Please let us know if you did.